# How to GET all data from DynamoDB with Lambda Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Using Axios, I tried to GET data from my API that is linked to Lambda Functions:

```
async getData() {
    await axios.get("https://...")
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
}
```

Here's my Lambda Function code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "ap-southeast-1"});

const params = {
  TableName : 'tablename'
}

async function listItems(){
  try {
    const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise()
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const data = await listItems()
    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
}
```

I have a DynamoDB table that I am trying to get all data points out of. EG: I have 3 sets of data with 7 attributes each.

Problem: when I test out the API on API gateway, I get all my data shown. However, I can't get the data to display on my console log.

How should I edit my data such that I can display it on my console log?

Comment: Which logs are you talking about? For Lambda logs, just console.log whatever you want in your handler and it will appear in CloudWatch Logs. Also, your `listItems` function is doing unneeded promise manipulation - just `return docClient.scan(params).promise()`.

Comment: @jarmod oh I wanted to see the console logs on my webapp, through the inspect tool. Nice, thanks for the heads up on the promise().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this code works fine I just forgot to deploy it. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you might be refering to your client console where you are calling axios from?

Your response is probably in Json format. Just do what you already did in your lamba and turn the JSON data into a string before logging it.

Instead of

```
console.log(response)
```

try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```

Comment: I tried to do that but still not getting a response. On AWS side when I tried, I got back a string of data, just that I am unable to get it displayed on my console log